# System.Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLine Listener, per thread

Tags: .net, tracelistener, trace-listener

I have a windows service which executes multiple threads to work things on.

At the same time, I use Trace listeners to collect some logging information. all works fine. But the main issue is, logging information (trace.writeline) is shared between all threads. So if something is written in one thread, it is visible and collected by all threads running at that time.

Is there a way that I can limit the trace listener to listen to currently thread only and not its sibling threads?

Using .NET framework 3.5 on Visual Studio 2008

thanks
   Sameers

Comment: Use trace listeners for communications sounds like you're abusing trace listeners. Although if you have to abuse them, you could probably abuse [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx) too and keep the information to be collected in a `ThreadLocal<YourInfo>` or something.

Comment: This library discusses System.Diagnostics multi-threading/multi-tier features, using Activity Id and the Correlation manager- https://ukadcdiagnostics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=LoggingPrimer